# Get the total sum of the weight of each file per line

Tags: awk, command, aix

I work with AIX and I need to find out the total sum of files created in the last 30 days within a directory. I already managed to extract to a file everything created in those 30 days, and with the command AWK I managed to create another file in which I have the weight of each one of those files. In conclusion, I already have a file with the weight of each line, but I need to add each to get the total weight and I do not know how to do it.
It is important to clarify that there are about 2,000,000 lines.
Thank you

Comment: Please give an example with `ls -l` with 3 files and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: What do you mean by _weight_? The size? The disk usage?

Comment: Do you really mean _created_ or _last modified_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a sum of the sizes of the files  listed one per line in `file.list` (so assumes file names don't contain newline characters):

```
perl -lne '$sum+=-s; END{print $sum}' file.list
```

Note that for symlinks, that counts the size of the target of the symlink.

That's the apparent size, which is typically different from the disk usage.

Answer (score 0):

This command will show the sum of file sizes which is changed the last 30 days:

```
find . -mtime -30 -exec stat -c %s {} \; | awk '{SUM+=$1}END{print SUM}'
```

Edit: sum of files

Comment: Thanks, but I already know the amount of lines. There are like 2.000.000. What I need is the sum of the size oh each one.

Answer (score 0):

I use this command and it works:

```
awk '{suma=0; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) suma=$i;sumatotal=sumatotal+suma; print sumatotal}' COT2
```

COT2 is the name of the file. I get the total size in KB, and then I convert this number to GB.